# Pinterest SDK: "PDKClient not found", what's wrong?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pinterest

I'm trying to implement Pinterest SDK into my Swift project. I've followed this install guide: https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/sdks/ios/

I just can't get this line working:

```
PDKClient.configureSharedInstanceWithAppId("0000")
```

It keeps on resulting to  `Use of unresolved identifier PDKClient`

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the PinterestSDK in the class (I guess AppDelegate, right?).

So, at the top of AppDelegate, add

```
import PinterestSDK
```

Then it should find the `PDKClient` object.

Comment: Facing same issue in objective c. I have tried import in both appdelegat.h & app delegate.m but not worked. Please suggest something